# Get the type of the the generic value

Tags: typescript

```
export type SearchDomainOperatorT = '<' | '>' | '|' | '=' | '<=' | '>=' | '!='
export type SearchDomainT<T> = [T, SearchDomainOperatorT, ] | '|'
export type SearchPayloadT<
  T extends keyof ERPTypes,
  F extends keyof ERPTypes[T]
> = {
  domain?: SearchDomainT<F>[]
  limit?: number
  offset?: number
  order?: string
} & BasePayloadT<T>

export type SearchPayloadWithCountT<
  T extends keyof ERPTypes,
  F extends keyof ERPTypes[T]
> = SearchPayloadT<T, F> & {
  count: true
}
export type SearchPayloadWithoutCountT<
  T extends keyof ERPTypes,
  F extends keyof ERPTypes[T]
> = SearchPayloadT<T, F> & {
  count: false
}
export type SearchQueryOverloadT = {
  <T extends keyof ERPTypes, F extends keyof ERPTypes[T]>(
    payload: SearchPayloadWithCountT<T, F>
  ): Promise<number[]>
  <T extends keyof ERPTypes, F extends keyof ERPTypes[T]>(
    payload: SearchPayloadT<T, F>
  ): Promise<number[]>
  <T extends keyof ERPTypes, F extends keyof ERPTypes[T]>(
    payload: SearchPayloadWithCountT<T, F>
  ): Promise<number>
}

export const searchQuery: SearchQueryOverloadT = async (payload) => {
  if (!token) {
    let { data } = await auth()
    token = data.access_token
  }
  return axios
    .post(process.env['E_URL'] + '/api/v2/search', payload, {
      headers: {
        DATABASE: process.env['E_DB']!,
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => res.data)
}
```

I have this function

what i want to achive is when i type:

searchQuery({
model: 'account.account',
domain: [['code', '=', 2510]],
with_company: company_id,
limit: 1,
})

then `domain: [['code', '=', 2510]]` it should only accept numbers as third parameter in the array because `code` is of type `number` in `ERPTypes[T]`

How do i do this?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] without any undeclared types or values, and without any dependencies on third party code unless your question is *about* such third party code.  So `ERPTypes` and `axios` stuff should be defined or replaced.